# How can these three equations be the equivalent?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to recreate these equations, but I can't find the operations I need to make to get to the equivalent solution below.

Can you help?

[image]

Comment: If this is true, then $\alpha_3$ is probably supposed to be nonnegative.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac34=\frac{\alpha_3^2}{\alpha_1^2+\alpha_3^2}\iff 3(\alpha_1^2+\alpha_3^2)=4\alpha_3^2 \iff 3\,\alpha_1^2=\alpha_3^2\iff\sqrt3\,\lvert\alpha_1\,\rvert=\lvert\alpha_3\,\rvert. $$